# Create an "includable" Rails controller action within helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, modularity

Is it possible to make an includable controller action within a Rails Helper through an `included` block? I'm thinking something like this:

```
module XablauHelper
  included do
    def my_shared_action
      true
    end
  end
end
```

Already tried doing it through `class.eval` block and through using like a class method i.e. `self.my_shared_action` but no success, I have already found a solution that is making a parent controller with the desired shared actions and inheriting from it, but for the sake of modular design I would like to make it a more "global" approach, so I could gemify my solution and reuse code, any suggestions that doesn't use inheritance?

Comment: You should use a concern http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding *controller* actions in a *helper* is probably the wrong choice, as these methods are intended for your *views*.

Consider using controller concerns instead, and including them where required. For example:

```
# in app/controllers/concerns/useful_functions_concern.rb
module UsefulFunctionsConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    rescue_from SomeException, with: :handle_access_denied
  end

  def useful_method
    # ...
  end

  protected
  def handle_access_denied
    # ...
  end
end

# in your controller
class XyzController < ApplicationController
  include UsefulFunctionsConcern

  def index
    useful_method
  end
end
```

Where common controller actions can be shared and the controllers have something in common e.g. they are all API controllers, also consider using inheritance to achieve this. For example:

```
# parent controller
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  def my_shared_action
  end
end

class SpecificApiController < ApiController
end
```

Comment: Clean and easy, thanks! I will try solution in next few days and mark as correct answer if successful.